# Determine the percentage of scores within a distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

> The scores obtained on a Test can be normally distributed with mean ${\mu}$=$100$ and standard deviation =$15$.What percentage of scores lie: Below $85$?

Progress:
used formula =${\frac{−}{}}$

Got -1 which corresponds to $0.15866$ on z score table

Since it asks for scores below $85$ do i minus $1 $ (the sum of all values)  from the value i got ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the value you've got $(0.15866)$ is the correct answer (because Z-score table gives the cdf of normal distribution, and the value you want is precisely $P(X\le-1)$).